Quantifying uncertainty in area measurements with python opencv
I'm attempting to use OpenCV in combination with a cheap USB microscope for real-time measurements of the area of samples we prepare via foil rolling, and are currently measured using calipers. Due to the irregular edges of some of these samples, I've been wanting to explore using image analysis rather than making assumptions about them being circular, rectangular, etc. In addition, I wanted to use mm grid paper (on a lightbox, to look for pinholes) behind the objects, to be able to get a pixel<->mm scale calibration on the fly.  This also greatly increases contrast, making it much easier to set thresholds and avoid issues with reflections, etc.
This has been successful, but while the area of the grid paper squares is determined accurately, when I image objects of known dimensions/area (such as a US penny), I get values that are 2-4% higher than expected.  This could be easily compensated for by changing the reference value until a calibration object is measured correctly, but i worry that this is just a bandaid for something I'm doing wrong, possibly with the morphological transformations / gaussian blur distorting the edges too much? The penny was a calibration check, but isn't able to be in the frame during normal use, which is why I wanted to use the grid paper for calibration in the first place.  The camera is mounted vertically overhead and centered, and trying to do the camera calibration seemed to add more spherical aberration than it improved things.
This leads to 2 primary questions:

What am I doing wrong here?
Is it possible to estimate the uncertainty in the areas calculated via cv2.contourArea(contour)?  Calipers normally let us get to within <0.5% uncertainty in area measurements, but quantifying an estimate of the uncertainty here would be important, though I don't see any information in the documentation about this...

Here's a sample input image as an example, with a standard US penny, on 5mm grid size paper:

The grayscale:

The code to detect the grid squares in the background, and return the mean value of the pixels<->mm calibration:
def measureGridSize(img, show_plot=True):
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY) 
    grid_area_threshold = 100
    known_grid_width = 5 # mm


    outerBox = np.zeros(gray.shape, np.uint8)
    gray = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray,(3,3),0)

    outerBox = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(gray,255,cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV,3,2)

    kernel = np.array((
        [0, 1, 0],
        [1, 1, 1],
        [0, 1, 0]), dtype="uint8")

    # Smooth out grid edges, remove background paper artifacts
    outerBox = cv2.dilate(outerBox,kernel,iterations = 1)
    outerBox = cv2.morphologyEx(outerBox, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, np.ones((2,2)))
    outerBox = cv2.morphologyEx(outerBox, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, np.ones((3,3)))
    outerBox = cv2.erode(outerBox,np.ones((3,4),np.uint8),iterations = 1)




    # Find contours
    contours, hierarchy  = cv2.findContours(outerBox, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

    area_list = []
    contour_list = []

    for contour in contours:
        # find moments of the image
        M = cv2.moments(contour)

        try:
            cX = int(M["m10"] / M["m00"])
            cY = int(M["m01"] / M["m00"])
        except ZeroDivisionError:
            cX = 0
            cY = 0
        
        # if the center is black, then the contour bounds a grid square
        if (outerBox[cY,cX] == 0) and (cY > 0) and (cX > 0):
            approxCurve = cv2.approxPolyDP(contour, 50, True)
            # if  the area is rectangle
            if len(approxCurve)==4: 
                # get lengths of sides
                (x,y,w,h) = cv2.boundingRect(contour)
                delta = 0.2;
                area = area = cv2.contourArea(contour)

                cv2.drawContours(img, [contour], -1, (255,0,0), 3)  # plot all found contours in blue
                cv2.drawContours(outerBox, [contour], -1, (255,0,0), 3)  # plot all found contours in blue

                # Check if contour looks like a square within tolerance delta
                if (abs((w/h)-1) < delta) and (area > grid_area_threshold) and (abs((w*h/area)-1) < delta) :
                        if area > 0:
                            area_list.append(area)
                            contour_list.append(contour)


    for (area,contour) in zip(area_list,contour_list):
        cv2.drawContours(img, [contour], -1, (0,255,0), 3)  # plot square-like contours in green


    # take the median or mean for grid scaling?
    # Remove edge cases to reject noise
    area_list.sort()
    if len(area_list) < 2:
        median = np.mean(area_list)
    elif len(area_list) < 3:
        median = np.mean(area_list[1:-1])
    else:
        median = np.mean(area_list[2:-2])
    pixels_per_mm = 0

    # take the side of a square which is the number of pixels per millimeter
    if np.size(median) == 1:
        pixels_per_mm = np.sqrt(median) / known_grid_width


    # Annotate area onto each detected grid square for comparison
    for contour in contour_list:
        area = cv2.contourArea(contour)
        if area > grid_area_threshold:

            x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(contour) 
            cv2.putText(img, '{0:.2f}'.format(area/(pixels_per_mm*pixels_per_mm)), (x, y+20), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.75, (0, 0, 255), 2) 


    return pixels_per_mm    

with output:

The code which takes a pixels_per_mm calibration and measures the area of objects over a set threshold:
def measureArea(img, pixels_per_mm):
    area_threshold = 100  # Reject small features


    # Convert to grayscale 
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY) 

    #
    # Threshold detection
    #

    blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (5, 5), 0)
    ret,th1 = cv2.threshold(gray,70,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
    
    contours,hierarchy = cv2.findContours(th1, 1, 2)
    for contour in contours:
        area = cv2.contourArea(contour)
        # Annotate object area onto image
        if area > area_threshold:

            x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(contour) 
            cv2.putText(img, '{0:.2f} cm2'.format(area/(pixels_per_mm*pixels_per_mm*100)), (x, y), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1, (0, 0, 255), 2) 

            cv2.drawContours(img, [contour], -1, (0,255,0), 1)  # plot square-like contours in green
            # print(area)

with output:

And finally the code which simply loops over a camera stream and calls the above two functions, and does a running average of the pixels per mm, to smooth out the output values of area (to avoid jitter in values real-time):
def acquireFromCamera(show_calibration=False):
    # Open the default camera (default was 0)
    cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

    pixel_scale_list = []

    # Loop over camera input stream frames
    while True:
        # Swapped from camera input to imread for posting to stackoverflow
        # 
        # ret, frame = cam.read()
        frame = cv2.imread('original_image.png')
        frame_copy = frame.copy()


        pixels_per_mm = measureGridSize(frame)

        # Get running average of pixel scale to smooth output areas
        if not np.isnan(pixels_per_mm):
            pixel_scale_list.append(pixels_per_mm)
        avg_pixel_scale = np.convolve(pixel_scale_list, np.ones(len(pixel_scale_list))/len(pixel_scale_list), mode='valid')


        print(avg_pixel_scale)
        measureArea(frame_copy, avg_pixel_scale[0])
        if show_calibration:
            cv2.imshow('Area Detection', frame_copy)


        # Display the captured frame
        cv2.imshow('Camera (Press q to exit)', frame)

        if cv2.waitKey(1) == ord('q'):
            break


    # Release the capture and writer objects
    cam.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()


acquireFromCamera(True)

Using known_grid_width = 5 # mm for the 5mm grid paper generates accurate measurement of the grid square areas (average 24.94398288816283 mm^2), but overestimates the expected 2.853 cm^2 area of the penny by about 3%. Bumping known_grid_width down to get the penny area correct makes the grid squares have areas of about 23.8 mm^2, which is a serious underestimation, and caliper measurements of the grid paper look to be consistent with 5mm grids. I don't think it's an issue with thresholds for measureArea(), and using mean vs median for getting a representative value of pixels per mm in each loop iteration also appears to be pretty insensitive. If it's an issue with the morphological transformations in the grid detection, the kernel choices were VERY sensitive as to how many grid squares where even detected. Short of a bandaid for using the penny area instead of known_grid_width (and thus negating the whole point of the paper), how can I reconcile the area results of the grid with the penny?
Any help you can provide a novice here would be massively appreciated - especially for estimating uncertainty in the area fits! Thanks!!

You do not take into account the thickness of the grid lines in your solution. 5 mm is not the side of the square, but the period. With a period of 5 mm and a line thickness of d mm, the area of ​​the square will be (5-d)².

is this a flatbed scan or is this taken with a camera? -- the only uncertainty you should have is the pixels that aren't clearly "coin" or clearly "background", which are the edge pixels. -- the calibration should be bang-on by construction. either do the calibration once, manually, by picking four points for a homography (in case of camera, otherwise 3 points for an affine transform), or put down some markers to automate the picking of those points. you could locate the intersections of the grid but don't expect that to be trivial. it'd take a moment of thought, which I don't have atm

Is the thickness of the penny relevant in comparison to the working distance of the camera/microscope objective? If so you might calibrate with respect to the wrong plane. The easiest to exclude such an influence would be to lift the grid to the same hight the top of penny is and repeat your calibration there.

Christoph Rackwitz is right: I manually worked on your original. Just used the length of 6 squares along one axis (and assumed that scaling factor is the same for the other one as well). I used that scaling factor to estimate the area of a handdrawn circle around your penny. Area was 285 - 286 mm^2. (All this quickly done in ImageJ). It might be that calibrating via squares introduces larger errors.

I see definite perspective distortion. the horizontal lines aren't parallel, neither are the verticals, and they even seem to curve a bit. this requires a homography to rectify and maybe even calibration of the lens distortion.

Well, I feel like an absolute idiot now - thanks for pointing out the issue, @AlexAlex, I can't believe I forgot about that....correcting for line widths fixed up the magnitude issues, thanks!!

@ChristophRackwitz - you're absolutely right re:distortion. This is done not with a flatbed scanner, but a cheap USB microscope (https://www.amazon.com/dp/B0066HA1PU) mounted on a ring stand, looking downwards at a lightbox with paper and objects laid on top. I tried to get perspective as close to vertical as possible
Trying findChessboardCorners() and calibrateCamera() only seemingly introduced more barrel distortion than help.  Currently looking into calibration via ChArUco boards... But that gives the camera matrix, applying a homography to adjust perspective is separate, correct?

a good calibration is not trivial to achieve. trust me when I say this. you'd have to mind a lot of things. browse https://calib.io/blogs/knowledge-base just ignore the distortion and just pick four point pairs, then use getPerspectiveTransform
